# Destructors are not guaranteed to be called

Tags: c#, .net

I came across the following quote "Desctructors are not guaranteed to be called." and this scares me a bit.

It goes on to say that even a try finally block can be interrupted, causing memory leaks. 
It does give a solution by either placing your code in CER (constrained execution region) or derive from the `CriticalFinalizerObject`.

My question is

1. What are the tradoffs by using `CriticalFinalizerObject`, if any?
2. Are their any cases were you found deriving from `CriticalFinalizerObject` was really usefull?
3. Should I only worry about using this when I start running into Memory leaks?

Comment: I don't think you should be worrying about this at all.

Comment: Could you give us the link to the source please.

Comment: @Jethro: `try/finally` can not be interrupted, the finally code will _always_ run..

Comment: @David, you don't think it would be a good Idea to cater for now so that in future you don't run into these "memory leaks" type of problems?

Comment: can you provide the link where was it quoted ?

Comment: @Jalal - "the finally code will always run" not if I pull out the plug or kill the process, it won't

Comment: @Jalal Aldeen Saa'd, I believe that is incorrect, the try finally can be interrupted. Asynchoronous events can cause this when at try finally is interrupted.

Comment: If you pull the plug you don't have to worry about leaks though, best cleanup ever ;)

Comment: @KiNGPiN, it comes from "Microsft Programming Visual C# 2008: The Language"

Comment: @Jethro If you carry this to the ultimate extreme your code will become much less readable and hence maintainable, all in the sake of protecting against events that happen essentially never.  That's a very poor trade off.

Comment: @Marc: of course if you pull out the plug it will not execute, ;) in fact you will only see _a dead pixels_

Comment: @David, I havn't see what what exactly you need to do to implement this but if it's just deriving from the "CriticalFinilazerObject" class it doesn't seem like much extra code, or doesn't have to make your code more un readable. Here's the link http://www.scribd.com/doc/24594593/Programming-Microsoft%C2%AE-Visual-C-%C2%AE-2008-The-Language

Comment: See, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157090/net-criticalfinalizerobject-what-does-it-really-do/1157105#1157105

Comment: @Jalal - emphasising an *always* is often a bad idea, is my point

Comment: @Marc: I will agree with that. you have a point :)

Comment: @Jethro How do you get all the classes that you have no control over to derive from `CriticalFinilazerObject`?

Comment: @David, I'm not really worried about the other classes, just classes that I would be creating. David I'm just interested it knowing these thing for furture reference, todays the first time I've ever heard of CriticalFinilazerObject, and how it can possibly help. I was really just interested in other peoples opinious and if anyone had the need to use this class.

Comment: This is a nice article about Critical finalizers that might answer some of your questions: [Joe Duffy's Weblog - Critical finalizers](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Y9vE3Qvm6cUJ:www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/default,date,2005-12-27.aspx) (offline but still present in Google cache)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you relying on desctructors ? most of the time you don't have any need of them.

Perhaps have a look at [IDisposeable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.idisposable%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and the Dispose Pattern.

Here some links that helpes me to understand this subject

-> [Everybody thinks about garbage collection the wrong way](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/08/09/10047586.aspx)

-> [How To implement dispose Pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/idisposable.aspx)

-> [Implementing Finalize and Dispose to Clean Up Unmanaged Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: I known what the IDisposable class does and how to use it, but as my post aboves states, this can be interrupted, cause memory leaks.

Comment: Ok. But this cases should be handled explicitly as for exmaple like mentioned in the other post with a Try{}finally{} block. 
Like Raymong Chen says:

>>A correctly-written program cannot assume that finalizers will ever run.<<

Comment: I'd rename your last link to "how not to clean up unmanaged resources". Unmanaged resources are the one thing that should use critical finalization.

Comment: I believe the warning "*Desctructors are not guaranteed to be called*" is there because of some obscure hedge cases.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding question #3: memory leaks would typically be caused by:

- Unmanaged resources not being freed.  For those, using IDisposable (with a fallback call to Dispose() in the finalizer) is the best approach.
- References to managed objects that are maintained because other objects still point to them, even though they are supposed to be removed.  IHMO, that's more a problem of code quality than a low-level issue with garbage collection.

Unless you run into actual memory leaks, you should not even worry about it, and not try to force any behavior.

Comment: that seems to be the general answer I'm getting form people. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the `IDisposable` interface for all resources that need to be destroyed, and use them in a `using` block.

Comment: So, how is a `using` block (technically) different from try-finally? (Yes, this question is rhetorical.)

Comment: This is not helpful. `using` is just syntactical sugar for `try/finally`.

Answer (score 0):

Typically the differences between a normal finalizers and critical finalizers only become important on AppDomain unload. Since most unmanaged resources automatically go away on process unload you usually need only to worry about critical finalization if you want to unload `AppDomain`s cleanly while keeping the process running.