# CriticalFinalizerObject usages misunderstanding?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, garbage-collection

I saw this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157090/net-criticalfinalizerobject-what-does-it-really-do) here but didnt get any answer to my thoughts.

for my understanding :

the reclaim of native reources will **Always** occur !

- when `GC` occurs  ( after the second round)
- calling dispose
- using `Using`
- crash of the program
- graceful terminate program

so why do i need to inherit from  `CriticalFinalizerObject`  ?

I don't see any situation where the reources Won't be reclaimed....

what am i missing ?

Comment: I don't think any Dispose() is executed when a program crashes.

Comment: @HenkHolterman you right -  Edited. ( my point is that the native resource will always be reclaimed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CriticalFinalizerObject` class does add some reliability to the Dispose/Finalize process. Like preventing `Thread.Abort()` et al.

> so why do i need to inherit from CriticalFinalizerObject ?

The main reason to use `Safehandle : CriticalFinalizerObject` is that it relieves you from dealing with the unmanaged resource pattern. A SafeHandle turns an unmanaged resource into a managed resource, see [Joe Duffy](http://joeduffyblog.com/2005/12/27/never-write-a-finalizer-again-well-almost-never/).

I don't think that as an Application programmer you will ever have to derive a class from CriticalFinalizerObject, but when you have to deal with  a 'handle' you should use `SafeHandle`.

Answer (score 4):

> my point is that the native resource will always be reclaimed

They are not.  Critical finalizers are important in custom hosting scenarios.  The kind where an unmanaged mission critical program hosts the CLR but cannot afford to simply terminate to let the operating system pick up the shrapnel when managed code crashes.

The best example is SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

It's all about being in control. Sometimes you want more than just the reclamation of native resources. Most- if not all of the native resource consumers in the BCL implement CriticalFinalizerObject. For example, FileStream implements CriticalFinalizerObject in order to flush out any cached data prior to closing the underlying filehandle.